# Dcjs cursor and tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I use `dc.js` and `d3-tip` for my lineChart and got next:

[image]

Now tooltip shows only when I do `mouseover` on some line. I need to show tooltip at any point of the chart and also show exact value near each axis like in chart [below](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/chart?p=GOOG#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%3D%3D):

[image]

Can I do it with dc.js?

*UPDATE:*

I found some `d3` [solution](http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3) but can't implement it with `dc.js`. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dc.js does not readily give you a way to do this. But you can add a renderlet or postrender on the chart to add something simple. I've had problems using d3-tip with dc.js and instead have been using a custom solution.

Put a fiddle together (based on [another time-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294588/dc-js-linechart-aggregated-by-month-year/47324208#47324208)) with value labels at the axes. 
https://jsfiddle.net/2bg6eyfq/2/  (UPDATED)

I've added in custom xyTips (tracking lines), because dc's xyTips only work for mouseover on the points. One tricky thing in dc.js is that you can't show the data points and set xyTipsOn(false), the points just won't show up.

```
chart
  .xyTipsOn(false)
  .renderDataPoints({radius: 3}) // these points won't show up
```

So, you leave xyTips on (default) and then you'd probably want to remove or hide dc's xyTips, not in my fiddle, but this is easy.

And you may also want to check out this question and answer from Gordon:
[how to highlight max and min points on lineChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389484/how-to-highlight-max-and-min-points-on-linechart/44392951#44392951)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in your fiddle custom tooltip shows not directly with cursor, but few points to right

Comment: @sf_ oh right, that's probably a browser issue. I updated the fiddle so the x-pos calculation uses d3.mouse instead of d3.event -- which should be more reliable.